# Why is the output for this code incorrect?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create code that calculates the percentage of values between a min and max value (inclusive). The output for this code should be 50.0, but I'm getting 100.0. Any ideas on why this is happening? Thanks!
Edit: The code compiles, and I'm not having issues with division. I'm confused as to why the numbers are different. Thanks!

```java
public class Test {
  public static double tempCheck(double[][] temps, double minTemp, double maxTemp) {
    int i;
    int betweenTemps = 0;
    double percentage = 0.0;
    int j;
    int numVals = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < temps[i].length; j++) {
        if (temps[i][j] >= minTemp && temps[i][j] <= maxTemp) {
          betweenTemps++;
        }
      }
      numVals++;
    }
    percentage = (betweenTemps / numVals) * 100;
    return percentage;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] temps = {
      { 72.0, 78.0, 74.5 },
      { 79.0, 80.0, 71.0 }
    };
    double minTemp = 70.0;
    double maxTemp = 75.0;
    System.out.println(tempCheck(temps, minTemp, maxTemp));
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `numVals++;` must be moved up one line. Also, integer division will give an integer as result, and `x/y` with `0 <= x < y` will be `0`. A remark: In java, you can initailize loop variables in the loop header: `for (int i = 0, ...)`

Comment: If you'd try to debug your code, you'd see why

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Well, it would also help to format your code properly.

Comment: People, please link the duplicate in the comments if there is one. In my opinion these are not duplicates of this exact and clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/B8rDJA

```java
public class Test {
  public static double tempCheck(double[][] temps, double minTemp, double maxTemp) {
    int i;
    int betweenTemps = 0;
    double percentage = 0.0;
    int j;
    int numVals = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < temps[i].length; j++) {
        if (temps[i][j] >= minTemp && temps[i][j] <= maxTemp) {
          betweenTemps++;
        }
        numVals++;
      }
    }
    percentage = ((double) betweenTemps / (double) numVals) * 100.0;
    return percentage;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] temps = {
      { 72.0, 78.0, 74.5 },
      { 79.0, 80.0, 71.0 }
    };
    double minTemp = 70.0;
    double maxTemp = 75.0;
    System.out.println(tempCheck(temps, minTemp, maxTemp));
  }
}
```

You need to increment `numVals` within the nested loop, and cast your result to a double for an accurate result.

Comment: I think the indentation is a bit off.

Comment: Oh wow, I just noticed this is Java, not C#, that takes me back a few years.

Comment: Hey! This is super helpful, but the result is still 100.0 when I run the program! I'm not sure what math error is happening but I'm super confused as to why the output is different than expected.

Comment: Hey @JennaCrist I made a typo, and have revised it. If you take a look at the code, I've moved the `numVals++` outside of the `if` block, so it's _always_ incremented for each value, and `betweenTemps` is only incremented for the right values. If you're using an IDE for development, you can do some interactive debugging and step through, see the comments on your question for more info.

Comment: I have added an ideone link so you can see the result of the code (https://ideone.com/B8rDJA).